# Getting "ValueError: The proto value '6' is already registered" when importing TensorFlow as tf

Tags: tensorflow, keras

To provide context, I'm a beginner working on a Kaggle competition and I've decided to run the .ipynb file locally instead of running it on the Kaggle kernel.

In the kernel I'm not getting this error by importing TensorFlow, but locally (in VSCode), I do.

I'm just writing some import statements for an image classification task, one of them is `import tensorflow as tf`, which I see others do.

This is the error I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 1
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py:38
     35 import sys as _sys
     36 import typing as _typing
---> 38 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     39 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     41 # Make sure code inside the TensorFlow codebase can use tf2.enabled() at import.

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py:42
     37 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     39 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     40 
     41 # Bring in subpackages.
---> 42 from tensorflow.python import data
     43 from tensorflow.python import distribute
     44 # from tensorflow.python import keras

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\__init__.py:21
     15 """`tf.data.Dataset` API for input pipelines.
     16 
     17 See [Importing Data](https://tensorflow.org/guide/data) for an overview.
...
    392     or type_spec_proto_enum <= 0
    393     or type_spec_proto_enum > 10):
    394   raise ValueError(f"The proto value '{type_spec_proto_enum}' is invalid.")

ValueError: The proto value '6' is already registered.
```

I tried to look up what a proto value is but got no results. I tried searching the TensorFlow documentation but the closest thing I found was about .proto files which I do not know about.

I copy pasted the error to look up online and I got no related results.

I have a bunch of other import statements in the first cell of my Jupyter notebook, but I tried deleting all of them and just writing `import tensorflow as tf`; I get the same error.

I haven't seen this before because I had the same import statements just yesterday and everything was working.

I have looked at the other posts here relating to errors when importing TensorFlow as tf, but as far as I can tell, none of the errors mention a proto value.

What is causing this error and what does it mean?

Comment: I realized I shouldn't have posted an image of the error trace, because I reread the 'how to ask' questions guide. I'll write out the error trace in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

just create a new notebook and try to import tensorflow as tf only and then print the tensorflow version if it works for you.
you can copy and past your hole code from your notebook to a newly created notebook